# Unity Android patch.obb file creation and use

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, apk-expansion-files

We are currently working on a Unity Android project that has to have localised mp4 streaming Videos. In order to achieve this I was hoping to put the video files in an expansion obb file, then we can have the same apk and submit it with different obb files according to language.

Unfortunately our application without the videos is still over 50Mb so we need to use the first "main.1.name.obb" for the application.

However we are allowed to also submit a second obb under the name "patch.1.name.obb". However I am having trouble making this and using it. Has anyone tried this with unity before?

The application builds and runs with the first obb file absolutely fine (i.e. the game works without videos) the problem is just in the patch obb creation.

I have tried to create the obb by using a linux zip command with 0% compression then renaming it to a .obb file with no luck. (e.g. patch.1.packname.zip to patch.1.packname.obb)

I have tried to create the obb using jobb tool, and it adds the videos fine but still in game they are not found/played.

The videos are definitely in an "assets" folder inside the obb files made (where I believe streaming assets have to be)

I have fudged the streaming Assets Path ( Application.streamingAssetsPath ) to replace "main" with "patch" and have seen through logcat that it is indeed trying to get the videos from the patch obb file. 
(e.g. "jar:file:///[storagelocation]/Android/obb/packname/patch.1.packname.obb!/vid01.mp4 )

Our version code in the AndroidManifest.xml if definitely 1. 
Can anyone suggest anything else to try or point out an clear errors I am making in trying to do this?

Let me know any more information you may need to help as well and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to create the patch file?

Comment: Unfortunately no. In the end we set up what we needed using perforce streams. We had a stream for each language, each had a custom mapping for the StreamingAssets folder. This way each language perforce stream looked the same but had the correct videos, allowing us to let Unity build itself the way it wanted to just using the 'main' obb file.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Unity before, but from my experience I can point out a few things I have found from working with '.obb' files:

- Simply renaming the '.zip' file to a '.obb' file will not work. You will need to make a folder named '.obb'. Then add all the needed resource files to this folder and then zip this folder, using 0% compression of course. Make sure that the zipped file contains only the resource files in the root and not a sub folder (the folder you made previously). Now you have a zip file named '.obb.zip'. At this point you can rename the file to '.obb'. Of course, the files may be in a sub folder inside the obb file (the assets folder in your case), but I am not sure about the consequences of this.
- In regards to the statement you made concerning the files that are not found after using the jobb tool, this is most likely due to a miss-spelling somewhere or in one of my cases, forgetting to rename the package after copying it from a previous app. I know this seems foolish and maybe insulting (in which case I deeply apologize), but it happens.

This answer is based on my personal experience and may be slightly off center, but here are some links I used:

- http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html
- http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html
- http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html